# Mono.Cecil - Wrong mscorlib version

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I am having issues trying to get Mono.Cecil to use the correct "mscorlib" version when using a TypeReference. I am adding a new variable to a Method and doing something along the following. However, it is adding a reference to the 4.0 mscorlib instead of the 2.0 mscorlib. I am having to run this application using the .NET Framework 4.5 so I am not able to use a lower version unless I re-write other people's code that I don't have access to.

```
TypeReference typeReference = CSharpModule.Import(Type.GetType("System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0]], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0"));
methodBody.Variables.Add(new VariableDefinition(typeReference));
```

I have tried to search around for an answer on how to get the correct version and I apparently have to use the Cecil Type System, but I am not able to find any examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix this by doing the following. Create a TypeReference using what is available to the MainModule.

```
assemblyDefinition.MainModule.GetType("System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean]]", true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should attempt to load the type by using `TypeReference` constructor,

https://github.com/lextm/obfuscar/blob/master/Obfuscar/Obfuscator.cs#L1204

My project Obfuscar shows an example of how to do so. You need to pay much attention to the `library.MainModule.TypeSystem.Corlib` part, so that the type is loaded from the proper mscorlib assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the lead, I was able to fix this issue by doing the following.

assemblyDefinition.MainModule.GetType("System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean]]", true)

Comment: @7H3LaughingMan glad to know that. Then you should post your answer and accept it.

Comment: This was the answer to a long and painful search for me, so thanks. Also, the link is out of date. Here's the updated version: https://github.com/obfuscar/obfuscar/blob/master/Obfuscar/Obfuscator.cs#L1344